# Azure Bot Function App trigger won't fire

Tags: javascript, azure, http, botframework, azure-functions

I have an Azure bot that I have been designing for learning purposes. However, I am at a loss on how to get the trigger to actually fire. The trigger is based on an HTTP request (see pic below) which is located in a function app. Authorization is set to anonymous and the route template is set to take a parameter for use elsewhere.

It seems to me that the trigger should fire when the bot receives an HTTP request signified by the req.body and req.body[0].id having content. But, it doesn't seem to work that way. The trigger runs fine with manually run.

I'm relatively new to things HTTP-related so any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Here is the code that matters which is the beginning of the index.js file used in the function app on Azure.

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    if (req.body && req.body[0].id) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    context.log(req.body);
```

Output (updated) for req.body[0].id and req.body:

[image]
[image]

Comment: So, how does your request look like? Make sure it's a POST, since you're testing for `req.body`.

Comment: Is the code your provide in the `index.js` under `messages` Function folder? It dosen't like a Function Bot's code snippet.

Comment: @evilSnobu, how can I test to see if it’s a POST? Again, forgive my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Gary, the code is from the index.js file, yes. It’s the first few lines.

Comment: Add a `context.log(req.body)` before the `if()` to check what you're really getting in the body.

Comment: Edit your original question and add the formatted output.

Comment: Everything is looking good. What exactly happens when you hit the function URL, do you ever get to this line `context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');`? Not really sure i understand your original problem.

Comment: Ok...apologies. Looks like I was posting the req.body from the trigger test. I have re-edited the original post to show what the Chrome dev tools is showing for activity following bot chat input. Thoughts?

Comment: It's `req.body.id` then. You can play around with this tool to master selectors, http://www.jsonquerytool.com/#/JavaScript

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you posting messages to the route `/messages/{guid}`? What is the endpoint route for your bot? Shouldn't you be listening to that route as well?